# Gradle build fails

Tags: java, gradle, build, dependencies

I have two Gradle projects, `A` and `B`. `B` is a simple Java application and is consumed by `A` as a compile project dependency. `A` is a web application.

Both `A` and `B` apply the `java` plugin, `A` applies the `war` plugin as well.

When building `A`, I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':war'.
> Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

When separately building `B` I get no errors. When building from root, I get no errors either. The issue shows up only when building `A`.

I've also tried copying the `B.jar` to the lib folder of `A` and setting a dependency:

```
compile files("lib/B.jar")
```

The build in this case works fine.

What configurations do I need to include to avoid the error?

Comment: You'll have to provide much more information.  Show your build scripts. How and what are you deploying? Is "B.jar" the only thing that doesn't get copied to the deployment folder? Are there any error messages?

Comment: @DavidM.Karr, the build scripts are very basic. The B script has nothing but eclipse configs and dependencies. The A script additionally has a task to build an rpm using the os-package plugin.

Comment: So, when copying a war file from build/libs to the deployment directory of your web server, the jar file magically disappears from the war file?

Comment: @JBNizet I do it from the STS.

Comment: can you include your build.gradle file?

Comment: does your parent gradle configuration knows about both subproject? I mean, do you have a root gradle configuration to make project A know about B and where to find it's build.gradle file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, when one subproject doesn't see another, if settings.gradle file is not on the parent directory for both subprojects and the subprojects in it are included via includeFlat. In this case you can call any task from your parent projects and all subprojects will know about each other, but it'll be unable to build separate subproject.

Any way, you need to show your project structure and build/settings files as well, to find out the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Stanislav. I've re-configured the root project and updated the root gradle.settings file, after which the build passes.

Comment: What did you add? I have already setup settings and gradle file for the project but still get the same error.