# Gradle projects build fails

Tags: java, gradle

gradle tasks

Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 stopped Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().

> Could not create service of type ChecksumService using BuildSessionScopeServices.createChecksumService().

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32112078/gradle-build-fails

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I have an Antivirus software Trend Micro which is blocking the gradle builds. After shutting down the anti virus software it works as expected.

Crazy that I forgot I have an antivirus software installed.